# How Do You Turn On Parenthesis Matching in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

How Do You Turn On Parenthesis Matching in Visual Studio 2005?

This is relevant to programming because there's lots of open/close parens... and paren-matching speeds things up a lot.

Comment: It was on by default last time I installed VS2005...placing the cursor after the closing parenthesis highlights them for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me Visual Studio (2008) does this automatically for C#, but not for C++.

To get paren matching in C++ I have to have Visual Assist enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking the following keyboard shortcut on the starting or closing parenthesis should jump to the matching one:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>

If they are unmatched you should be able to spot this pretty quickly.

I didn't have to enable anything in VS2005 to use this functionality.